# retrieve data from database in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I have two tables called events and trainers in my project.events table contain trainer's id. I have drop down menu which contains trainer's name as follows.

```
<% form_tag "/events/find_trainer" do %>
<%= collection_select("event", "trainer", @trainers , :id, :name, {:prompt => true}) %>
<%= submit_tag "search" %>
<%end%>
```

then i created find_trainer method in controller to retrieve data of events table.

```
def find_trainer
@events=Event.find(:all, :conditions=> { :trainer=>params[:id]})
  end
```

This will not retrieve anything from the database.i am using postgresql and ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8 versions. I could not understand my fault.. Can anybody help me?

Comment: This is a pretty basic question. You should ready this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your associations defined with has_many, you don't need to use find that way

You just find the trainer:

```
@trainer = Trainer.find_by_id(params[id])
```

and then can access all it's events with

```
@trainer.events
```

For this to work you need in your trainer model:

```
has_many :events
```

in your Event model:

```
belongs_to :trainer
```

and a trainer_id column in the events table

**edit**

Naming the foreign_key column 'trainer' is a bad idea, it breaks Rails conventions and makes your life more difficult. You can tell Rails which column name to use like this:

```
has_many :events, :foreign_key => :trainer
```

and

```
belongs_to :trainer, :foreign_key => :trainer
```

but you should avoid this if any possible and change your migration instead and rebuild your database. This feature is mainly thought to allow using databases from old projects, not written in Rails.

In addition the other errors tell you, that there is no value in params[:id]. Do you have fixture data in the database?

To just see, if it works at all, you could start with

```
@trainer = Trainer.first
```

This would take the first trainer and then

```
@trainer.events
```

should work, if any events for this trainer exist. Then you can find out what's wrong with params[:id], most likely some link doesn't work properly, maybe your form is wrong or the routing to your controller has errors.

You are trying too many things at once, without having made sure, that the basics work. That's why we normally do test driven development in Ruby on Rails.

First set up the Trainer model. Then test it, make sure there are trainers by writing and loading fixtures, and that Rails can find them.

After that add the events model (and some fixture data again). If you don't explicitly write tests, then at least use the Rails console (i think it was the command script/console in Rails 2.x) to test. Only if you are 100% sure it works on the model level, start writing controllers. That way you have to handle only one error at any given moment.

Comment: I got an exception..                                                 undefined method `events' for nil:NilClass                           what should I do? I already defined my associations with has_many...

Comment: @Rosh: What exception and where? That's totally primitive Rails code, it must work. Do you have the trainer_id column or is it named trainer?

Comment: @Rosh: undefined method `events' for nil:NilClass says it didn't find a trainer. Then @trainer is nil and nil doesn't have "events"

Comment: i am novel to the rails and actually I don't know lot of things.That is why I am asking stupid questions. In my project i used event calendar plugin and if i used has_many :events, :foreign_key => :trainer in my event model, it will give exception called trainer without an id.what should i do for this?

Comment: shall i change my table column into trainer_id?

Comment: @Rosh: Really best thing to do would be to simply change your database, since you most likely set it up new anyway and use trainer_id. Ignoring Rails conventions will give you just a lot of trouble if you are not an experienced developer.

Comment: @Rosh: you are welcome, all of us had to start some day and Rails adds a small burden to the beginner, but you will see, that it pays after some time. Have a look at some good tutorial like [this one](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book_)

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys are usually named after the table at which they point.

Try this?

```
@events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => {:trainer_id => params[:id]})
```

Comment: PGError: ERROR:  column events.trainer_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "events" WHERE ("events"."trainer_id" IS NULL)...
                                      ^
: SELECT * FROM "events" WHERE ("events"."trainer_id" IS NULL)     I got this exception ....

Comment: @Rosh: this look as if you named the foreignkey column in the events table 'trainer' instead of 'trainer_id'. This would be a bad idea, since it breaks Rails conventions. You should change that if any possible. This would make problems for my answer as well, since has_many and belongs_to would need to be slightly changed to reflect your usage of column names.

Comment: @Rosh: The part ("events"."trainer_id" IS NULL) additionaly says, that there is no value in params[:id], hence it's NULL, that's why Rails cant't find a trainer with Trainer.find_by_id

Answer (score 0):

The params from this post method will be params[:event][:trainer] this will carry the value of id.

and also the column value of the foreign_key have to check.